# I'm receiving Undefined offset error

Tags: php, arrays

Why do I receive `Undefined offset error`? I'm trying to add `10,20,20` for each element in array. Please help. Thanks in advance

```
<?php
    $arr = array("a","b","c");
    $counter = 0;
    $status = array();
    foreach($arr as $a){
        $status[$counter] += 10;
        $status[$counter] += 20;
            $status[$counter] += 20;
        echo $status[$counter]."<br>";
        $counter ++;
    }
?>
```

Error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 6
300

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 6
300

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 6
300
```

`

Comment: Why not just `$status[$counter] += 50;`?

Comment: @Jack, Idk why the `$counter` is required, can't we use the `key` itself ? Pretty unclear question.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I'm not sure either :)

Comment: You want to add 50 to a , b and c ? So it should be 50a, 50b and 50c or what ?

Comment: @rrr, Please post the expected output on your question. Like how your final array should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `$status` is an empty array, so when you attempt to add something to an undefined index you will see that notice (only for the first time).

To initialize `$status` as an array with values 0 based on the number of elements in `$arr`:

```
$status = array_fill(0, count($arr), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to add 10 in a undefined array element in this line:

```
$status[$counter] += 10;
```

try like this:

```
  $arr = array("a","b","c");
  $counter = 0; 
  $status = array(); 
  foreach($arr as $a){ 
  $status[$counter] = 10;//assign first 
  $status[$counter] += 20; //concate with assigned element
  $status[$counter] += 20;
   echo $status[$counter]."<br>"; 
   $counter ++; 
 }
```

it should not provide any notices.

Comment: Isn't this same what Jack and Mike said 12 mins ago ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using an 'add and assign' operator.

If you just want to assign a value then

```
$status[$counter] = 10;
```

Will work just fine.

However, you're asking PHP to add something to an existing element in your array, but there's no element there yet since you haven't initialised it. Just initialise your array before you start your loop.